# How to Hide / Remove Share Button in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I am looking for a way to remove / Hide the SHARE Button from the SharePoint Modern page, It would be great if someone can help me with this? any help will be appreciated

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way of removing or hiding it at the moment.
You can control the behaviour of it though, [more information on that here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off).

There is a UserVoice request for the possibility to hide it, you can vote for that feature here:
https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/14343132-provide-an-option-to-disable-the-share-button

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is deploy [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant so you could hide the share button for specific page by custom CSS.

```
<style>
button[data-automationid="ShareSiteButton"]{
display:none
}
</style>
```

OR [SPFx Applications Customiser](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss) to inject custom CSS

[image]

Comment: ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:35:5
    at req_ (C:\users\tejast\Documents\GitHub\sp-dev-fx-extensions\samples\react-application-injectcss\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\users\tejast\Documents\GitHub\sp-dev-fx-exten

Comment: I keep getting this reference Error...

Answer (score 0):

This CSS did the trick for me:

```
button[data-automation-id="shareButton"]
    {
        display: none !important
    }
```